# Wont a infinite monitor on azure functions not also create infinite amount of replays?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am learning azure functions and durable functions. Looking at the examples for the monitor pattern:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-monitor

```
public static async Task Run(DurableOrchestrationContext monitorContext, ILogger log)
{
    MonitorRequest input = monitorContext.GetInput<MonitorRequest>();
    if (!monitorContext.IsReplaying) { log.LogInformation($"Received monitor request. Location: {input?.Location}. Phone: {input?.Phone}."); }

    VerifyRequest(input);

    DateTime endTime = monitorContext.CurrentUtcDateTime.AddHours(6);
    if (!monitorContext.IsReplaying) { log.LogInformation($"Instantiating monitor for {input.Location}. Expires: {endTime}."); }

    while (monitorContext.CurrentUtcDateTime < endTime)
    {
        // Check the weather
        if (!monitorContext.IsReplaying) { log.LogInformation($"Checking current weather conditions for {input.Location} at {monitorContext.CurrentUtcDateTime}."); }

        bool isClear = await monitorContext.CallActivityAsync<bool>("E3_GetIsClear", input.Location);

        if (isClear)
        {
            // It's not raining! Or snowing. Or misting. Tell our user to take advantage of it.
            if (!monitorContext.IsReplaying) { log.LogInformation($"Detected clear weather for {input.Location}. Notifying {input.Phone}."); }

            await monitorContext.CallActivityAsync("E3_SendGoodWeatherAlert", input.Phone);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // Wait for the next checkpoint
            var nextCheckpoint = monitorContext.CurrentUtcDateTime.AddMinutes(30);
            if (!monitorContext.IsReplaying) { log.LogInformation($"Next check for {input.Location} at {nextCheckpoint}."); }

            await monitorContext.CreateTimer(nextCheckpoint, CancellationToken.None);
        }
    }

    log.LogInformation("Monitor expiring.");
}
```

1. If that was changed to an infinite monitor?
2. Won't the history of the context growth to where it causes a problem?
3. Am I correct that whenever one call await CreateTimer, the current method awaits until the timer is meet but a replay is also executed when the timer trigger?
4. What then the next time, is there the initial method + 2 replays running?
5. What happens if the platform moves the function to a new host, does it then cancel that initial method and it will continue due to a replay is played on the new host?

Comment: did you read the article about eternal orchestrators? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-eternal-orchestrations

Comment: Solves 1 and 2. Question 3,4 and 5 would still be valid for eternal orchestrators